# Firestore Database Creation Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have attempted to create a new Firestore database for an Xcode project I'm working on. I have added the app the to the Firebase project and implemented Firebase into my app. Every time I try to create a Firestore database, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBU5q.png). Anyone know what it is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you activate Datastore previously? For some reason, users can not use both Firestore and Datastore within the same project.

The same applies if you has enabled App Engine on this project before and has chosen any region besides us-central (the only Firestore region during beta).

The workaround at this moment is create a new project for Firestore.

Comment: I created this project from scratch. I created for the sole purpose of using Firestore. I'll have to look into the choosing of us-central to see if that helps.

Comment: I appreciate your response and I just reloaded the page and it seemed to work, so thank you!

Comment: Excellent news! If you want to keep tracking of the Firebase status in general you can visit https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!